# translating frame to iframe

Tags: html, iframe

I am transitioning a page that used to have frames to an iframe approach to be compatible moving forward. The basic look is very simple, it's a fixed pixel height header, and then the variable height content taking up the rest of the screen space with a different page in it.

I have accomplished this via:

```
    <style type="text/css">
    * {overflow:hidden}
    div#header {position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;right:0px;height:86px;overflow:hidden;margin:0px;padding:0px;}
    div#wrapper {position:absolute;top:86px;left:0px;right:0px;bottom:0px;overflow-y:auto;margin:0px;padding:0px;}
</style>
```

and

```
            <div id="header">
            content in top
        </div>

        <div id="wrapper">
        <iframe src="http://someotherwebpage" style="width:100%;height:100%;" />
        </div>
```

While this works perfectly in Chrome and IE, it fails in FF and others (i.e. iPhone). Any ideas how I can further improve this to work on all browsers?

Edit: To be specific, by "fail" I mean the scroll bar does not show up (vertical scroll bar), and thus I cannot scroll up or down in FF/others. In Chrome/IE, it shows up and works as expected.

Comment: An iFrame is the last thing I would use, You should think about using a div instead of an iframe and load the data using ajax (assuming the iframe is on the same domain as your parent website).

Comment: the page i'm loading is on a completely different site. i'm basically adding a header to other content, like stumbleupon

Comment: You have `* {overflow:hidden}`. I would look into that first.

Comment: Close your iframe tag. Might be your issue!

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `* {overflow:hidden}` to `* {overflow:auto}`